# SonarLint for Sonarqube 4.4.1

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-coverage, metrics, sonarlint

Thanks for very useful and excellent product, it is really helpful to us, when we have used one of our previous java project with SonarQube5.3 as server from Eclipse to maintain Quality Project in last year. Currently, We are using Sonarqube 4.4.1 as our client is having for couple of projects. We would like to utilize SonarLint in our development environment to connect to Sonarqube 4.4.1 server. I would like to know, if you have any road map/plans to cover Sonarqube 4.4 version also, as i have seen your recent release 2.1.0, which would be support SonarQube 4.5. Regards, Joseph

Comment: You should ask about that on https://jira.sonarsource.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for customer support, specifically requesting a given feature in a future release. See [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we won't add backward compatibility for versions older than the 4.5 (which is already quite old). Maintaining this compatibility is costly and slows down the evolution of SonarLint.

And thanks for the kind words :)